# two ejb jar files with same name in different EAR projects conflict with each other on jboss 7.1

Tags: maven, ejb, jboss7.x, pom.xml, jboss5.x

I'm migrating projects from `Jboss 5.1` to `jboss 7.1`

I have two EARs, which run on the same Jboss. They contain ejb project inside and both ejb jar files are called  `services.jar` due to `finalname` tag in `EJB_PROJECT/pom.xml`

```
    <build>
        <finalName>services</finalName>
            .....
    </build>
```

On Jboss 5.1 it worked fine, but now i get error :

```
    18:07:16,858 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."my1.ear"."services.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."my1.ear"."services.jar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "services.jar" of deployment "my1.ear"  
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]  
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018027: Failed to add JBoss Web deployment service  
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:320)  
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:114)  
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    ... 5 more  
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./services.realm is already registered  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:227) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:560) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:307) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]  
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:269)  
    ... 7 more
```

Is there a way to make this work without changing `finalname` tag's value? If I change it, then url to my application changes and i don't want that.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "url to my application"? because if it's a JNDI url, you just can't have two modules with the same one.

Answer (score 5):

Try having this in your META-INF/ejb-jar.xml of your EJB:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<javaee:ejb-jar version="3.1"
    xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">

    <javaee:module-name>some-name-you-want-for-your-ejb</javaee:module-name>
</javaee:ejb-jar>
```

As per EJB specification, that should override the file name for JNDI. This is clarified for example in [EJB FAQ](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html):

> <module-name> defaults to the unqualified name of the ejb-jar file or
>   .war file in which the EJB component is defined, minus the file
>   extension.   The <module-name> can be explicitly specified using the
>   <module-name> element of the ejb-jar.xml (for ejb-jars) or web.xml(for
>   EJB components defined in .wars).